# SwiftUI ForEach not updating following changes to the ObservableObject class array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, observableobject

### Background

In my app I have an array of friends that can be added to from another view. I've stored this array of friends in a class which is an `ObservableObject`. Within my main view, `FriendListView`, I am using a `ForEach` to display a custom view for each friend that a user has added.

I have not been able to add to the array and have the list display the new item. I have tried two different attempts based upon what I was able to understand and put together. Any help that someone is able to provide would be greatly appreciated. I currently have the method to display the 2nd view where I will be adding a new friend commented out and a method to automatically save a new one exists as a navigation bar item.

### Attempts

#### Attempt #1

I was successful in displaying the list of friends if they were appended to the array during the class initializer. Calling the class method to add to the array from another view seems to work based upon me being able to print the contents of the array but the UI does not update.

This was completed by using a `ForEach(0..<Array.count)` approach but I received the following console error after adding a new item.

**Error**

```
ForEach<Range<Int>, Int, HStack<TupleView<(Spacer, FriendView, Spacer)>>> count (4) != its initial count (3).
`ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data.
Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an explicit `id`!
```

**Model Code**

```swift
struct Pet: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var breed: String
}

class FriendModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var petList = [Pet]()
    
    func addFriend(name: String, breed: String) {
        petList.append(Pet(name: name, breed: breed))
    }
    
    init() {
        petList.append(Pet(name: "Woofer", breed: "Dawg"))
        petList.append(Pet(name: "Floofer", breed: "Dawg"))
        petList.append(Pet(name: "Super", breed: "Dawg"))
//        petList.append(Pet(name: "Dooper", breed: "Dawg"))
//        petList.append(Pet(name: "Booper", breed: "Dawg"))
    }
}
```

**UI Code**

```
struct FriendListView: View {   
    
    @EnvironmentObject var dataModel: FriendModel
    
    @State private var displayAddFriendSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(0..<self.dataModel.petList.count) { pet in
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            FriendView(
                                name: self.dataModel.petList[pet].name,
                                breed: self.dataModel.petList[pet].breed,
                                screenWidth: geo.size.width,
                                randomPic: Int.random(in: 1...2)
                            )
//                            FriendView(
//                                name: self.dataModel.petList[pet].name,
//                                breed: self.dataModel.petList[pet].breed,
//                                screenWidth: geo.size.width)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }// End of ScrollView
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Furiends"))
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: self.showAddFriend) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
                
                )
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$displayAddFriendSheet) {
                        AddFriendView()
                }
                
            }// End of NavigationView
        }// End of GeometryReader geo1
    }// End of body
    
    func showAddFriend() {
//        self.displayAddFriendSheet.toggle()
        self.dataModel.addFriend(name: "Jax", breed: "Doodle")
        print(dataModel.petList)
        
    }// Enf of showAddFriend
    
}// End of FriendListView
```

#### Attempt #2

After seeing the error from the first attempt, I read how I could skip the range and provide just the array as a part of the `ForEach` since I am adhering to the `Identifiable` protocol with my UUID in the `Pet` struct. With the model code remaining the same as my first attempt, my updated UI code is below. Note the only change was to the ForEach but I received the following error:

**Error**
`Cannot convert value of type '[Pet]' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'`

**UI Code**

```
struct FriendListView: View {   
    
    @EnvironmentObject var dataModel: FriendModel
    
    @State private var displayAddFriendSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(self.dataModel.petList) { pet in  // <--- Changed to directly reference the array
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            FriendView(
                                name: self.dataModel.petList[pet].name,
                                breed: self.dataModel.petList[pet].breed,
                                screenWidth: geo.size.width,
                                randomPic: Int.random(in: 1...2)
                            )
//                            FriendView(
//                                name: self.dataModel.petList[pet].name,
//                                breed: self.dataModel.petList[pet].breed,
//                                screenWidth: geo.size.width)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }// End of ScrollView
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Furiends"))
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: self.showAddFriend) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
                
                )
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$displayAddFriendSheet) {
                        AddFriendView()
                }
                
            }// End of NavigationView
        }// End of GeometryReader geo1
    }// End of body
    
    func showAddFriend() {
//        self.displayAddFriendSheet.toggle()
        self.dataModel.addFriend(name: "Jax", breed: "Doodle")
        print(dataModel.petList)
        
    }// Enf of showAddFriend
    
}// End of FriendListView
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the remaining try to access by subscription confuses compiler, so as far as `Pet` is `Identifiable` the following should work

```
ForEach(self.dataModel.petList) { pet in
    HStack {
        Spacer()
        FriendView(
            name: pet.name,        // << pet is not index
            breed: pet.breed,      // << so access by property
            screenWidth: geo.size.width,
            randomPic: Int.random(in: 1...2)
        )
 // .. other code
```

Comment: I'm able to get past the compiler issues and load the initial list. I can now add to the list but the list isn't reflective of the changes. There are no warnings in the console either. Any thoughts on why this is? My dataModel is created as `@EnvironmentObject var dataModel: FriendModel` and I am passing an instance of that class in my SceneDelegate as an environment variable.